# Use Bitrix-REST-Api to view a contact

Tags: bitrix

Is it possible to use the REST-API of Bitrix to View a Contact (open contact detail view)?
In the API-Documentation (found under https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/) I cannot find any informatione about showing Views (only for showing Calendar Detail view).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this methode:
https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/crm/contacts/crm_contact_list.php

There are also some examples.
Perhaps its help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).